# Error bounds for finite differences, or in general any numerical differentiation

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, finite-differences

For numerical differentiation of $\frac{df}{dx}$ at $x=0$, suppose I use finite difference methods of $p^{th}$ order, which produces $O(h^p)$ error, where $h$ is the step size I use for numerical differentiation. From what I see, I can find error  bounds (no, $O
(h^{p})$ is just asymptotic error bound, and what I want is more specific) for 1st-order, 2nd-order, 3rd-order finite difference, but not for general $p^{th}$ order case. What would be the formula for the $p^{th}$-order error bound?

Also, would there be a better numerical differentiation than finite difference methods in terms of error bound and what would be error bounds? (for example, $f(x) = \cos(x)$)

I will accept any answer that answers the first question - I am fine having an answer to the first question only.

Comment: Have you use Taylor's formula to derive an exact representation of the error from which an error bound can be obtained? Error bounds are quite often pessimistic. Have you considered the problem of obtaining accurate error estimates?

Comment: Yes. But using Taylor series seems quite clunky for obtaining error bound. Taylor series itself is elegant, but the resulting manipulation often is not. Which is why I ask for error bounds, as it simplifies the matter, however pessimistic such bounds may be.